# Binary search tree problem: transform a BST into a BST where the number of nodes differ by 1 between the left and right

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, graph-theory

I am doing a problem that requires me to balance any binary search tree, with a criteria that the left and right subtree on each level should have the same amount of nodes or at most 1 node difference

How can I approach this problem?
So far I have transformed the tree into a linked list.. and thats it. Im pretty sure thats the first step but not too sure. I have looked everywhere for resources, but the closest thing I could find was day-stout-warren algorithm which balances based on height and not amount of nodes.

Comment: Why would it be useful to transform it into a linked list? Seems like the goal is to find the median element and make that the root node.

Comment: @kaya3 yes, considering the tree is unsorted, the linked list will order it and I assume it will mean less rotations, starting from the middle. I assumed we just rotate the next middle on the left side, and the right side, and so on, but I dont think that works..

Comment: How could a binary search tree be unsorted?

Comment: Unsorted in the sense the numbers arent ascending. A binary search tree is sorted in the sense an inorder traversal would give you the nodes in ascending order if im not mistaken. You cant find the median without creating another linked list and since thats the model which will likely reduce the total rotations, i figured i would just transform the tree to a linked list

Comment: You can find the median without putting the nodes into another data structure. Who said you can't? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+median+binary+search+tree

Comment: If you know how to traverse the tree in order, and you know how to count the nodes, then you know how to stop counting when you get halfway. There is no need to keep track of all the numbers you see along the way.

Comment: Once you have found the node containing the median, you just need to do rotations to move it up the tree, level-by-level, until it's the root node.

Comment: @kaya3 I solved the problem using a linked list, but I fear working on the tree, making the median the root and doing it for each subtree as you go along would only increase the total amount of rotations, thus the overall time complexity especially since there is also another criterion, (forgot to be concise in my question, my bad) that if the left-right amount of nodes = -1, the tree is not valid. I initially also made the tree into a linked list because the day stout warren is the fastest algo to height balance a tree, and the first step is to create a backbone.I assume thats why it was fast

Comment: Ah, I see now that you want this property to apply for every node, not just the root node. I still think there is no need for a linked list, but it's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python solution which works in O(n) time, in-place with O(h) auxiliary space where h is the height of the tree; the only auxiliary data structure is the stack required for the recursive functions.

It works using a generator function which iterates over the tree *while the consumer is changing the tree*, but we make local copies of the `left` and `right` subtrees before yielding them, so the consumer can reassign those without breaking the generator. (Actually only a local copy of `right` is really required, but I made local copies of both anyway.)

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __repr__(self):
        # display for debug/testing purposes
        def _r(n):
            return '*' if n is None else '(%s ← %r → %s)' % (_r(n.left), n.data, _r(n.right))
        return _r(self)

def balance(root):
    def _tree_iter(node):
        if node is not None:
            # save to local variables, could be reassigned while yielding
            left, right = node.left, node.right
            yield from _tree_iter(left)
            yield node
            yield from _tree_iter(right)
    
    def _helper(it, k):
        if k == 0:
            return None
        else:
            half_k = (k - 1) // 2
            left = _helper(it, half_k)
            node = next(it)
            right = _helper(it, k - half_k - 1)
            node.left = left
            node.right = right
            return node
    
    n = sum(1 for _ in _tree_iter(root))
    return _helper(_tree_iter(root), n)
```

Example:

```py
>>> root = Node(4, left=Node(3, left=Node(1, right=Node(2))), right=Node(6, left=Node(5), right=Node(8, left=Node(7), right=Node(9))))
>>> root
(((* ← 1 → (* ← 2 → *)) ← 3 → *) ← 4 → ((* ← 5 → *) ← 6 → ((* ← 7 → *) ← 8 → (* ← 9 → *))))
>>> balance(root)
(((* ← 1 → *) ← 2 → (* ← 3 → (* ← 4 → *))) ← 5 → ((* ← 6 → *) ← 7 → (* ← 8 → (* ← 9 → *))))
```

Comment: Is the tree like so? https://imgur.com/a/j91DQ6S . If so, theres just a tiny mistake probably due to my poor question wording. In subtrees 2 and 7, the difference between the left subtree nodes and the right is -1. Thanks so much anyways btw for the code. It helps me, i can adjust it myself.

Comment: Ah, in that case swapping `half_k` and `k - half_k - 1` should be sufficient.

Comment: I ended up making the tree into a vine, and then manipulating it into the tree I want. I was unable to implement your algorithm as it wouldnt work with my binary tree class. It helped me with the pseudocode alot. Thanks.Since I see you are doing a PhD, I wanted to know, wouldnt changing it into a linked list and then manipulating it occupy less aux space? I know its has nothing to do with this problem, but isnt the day-stout-warren algorithm only efficient because of the conversion into a linked list?

Comment: Oh, I see now that you meant reusing the tree nodes' internal pointers to form a linked list; that wasn't clear from what you were proposing. Yes, in that case you should be able to do it with O(1) auxiliary space instead of O(h). If you were able to get it working that way, then you might want to post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: thanks for the response. Today, I learnt that my classmates arrive balancing trees  10x less time than me, so for certain the linked list is not the way to go(they just worked on the tree itself). But my brain atm is too small to crack the code to do it within the tree. Sorry for being unclear in the question, I guess I prolly should work more on my english skills than my python skills haha

Answer (score 0):

Add all nodes to an array in inorder traversal, then it should be roughly like this:

```
fun buildBalanced(
    array: Array, 
    start: Int = 0, 
    end: Int = array.length) -> Node {
  if (start >= end) {
    return nil
  }
  let middle = (start + end) / 2
  return new Node(
      array[middle], 
      buildBalanced(array, start, middle),
      buildBalanced(array, middle + 1, end))  
}
```